# Change Rijndael decryption logic from C# to Python

Tags: python, c#, rijndael, rijndaelmanaged

I have some already encrypted data which needs to be decrypted using python. The decryption logic in C# looks as given below.

```cs
using System.Security.Cryptography;
private const string Url_ENCRYPTION_KEY = "abcd123456";
private readonly static byte[] URL_SALT = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Url_ENCRYPTION_KEY.Length.ToString());
public static string Decrypt(string inputText) {
    
    try {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputText)) {
            RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
            byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(inputText.Replace(" ", "+"));
            PasswordDeriveBytes secretKey = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Url_ENCRYPTION_KEY, URL_SALT);

            using (ICryptoTransform decryptor =
                rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor(secretKey.GetBytes(32), secretKey.GetBytes(16))) {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedData)) {
                    using (CryptoStream cryptoStream =
                        new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
                        byte[] plainText = new byte[encryptedData.Length];
                        int decryptedCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
                        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText, 0, decryptedCount);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        //clsErrorHandler.LogError(ex);
    }
    return inputText;
}
```

I have tried libs like pprp and python's cryptography but the solutions out there use PBKDF2, while the C# code here supplies the decryptor bytes of key and salt as key and IV values.
From what I looked the PasswordDeriveBytes function basically work as a somewhat modified PBKDF1,
but all of the solutions I tried fail with somekind of esoteric this size doesn't match with that size errors.
Here is one implementation of PasswordDeriveBytes I found floating out there but I am at a loss on how to do something similar to `secretKey.GetBytes(32)` and creating a decryptor

```py
import hashlib
from base64 import b64decode

def MS_PasswordDeriveBytes(pstring, salt, hashfunc, iterations, keylen):
    if iterations > 0:
        lasthash = hashlib.sha1(pstring+salt).digest()
        iterations -= 1
    else:
        print("Iterations must be > 0")
    #If iterations is 1 then basically the same thing happens as 2 based on my testing
    #if iterations == 0 and keylen > len(lasthash):
        #print("Dunno what happens here")
        #return -1
    for i in range(iterations-1):
        lasthash = hashlib.sha1(lasthash)
    bytes = hashlib.sha1(lasthash).digest()
    ctrl = 1
    while len(bytes) < keylen:
        bytes += hashlib.sha1(str(ctrl)+lasthash).digest()
        ctrl += 1
    return(bytes[:keylen])


stpass = 'amp4Z0wpKzJ5Cg0GDT5sJD0sMw0IDAsaGQ1Afik6NwXr6rrSEQE='
slt = 'aGQ1Afik6NampDT5sJEQE4Z0wpsMw0IDAD06rrSswXrKzJ5Cg0G='
initv = '@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8'
enc_str = b64decode('B5YDTLEDBjd+8zy5lzEfjw==')
derbytes = MS_PasswordDeriveBytes(stpass, slt, hashlib.sha1, iterations=2, keylen=32)
```